# Deploying Oracle.DataAccess with Any CPU mode to work in both 32 bit and 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have some application which i am migrating from Microsoft OracleClient to ODP.NET(Oracle DataAccess). My machine has windows 7 64 bit with 32 bit oracle installed. Now when i build the application in Any CPU mode(without checking prefer 32 bit) and when i run it gives the error message ""Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies"

If i build application in x86 mode or Any CPU mode with Prefer 32 bit then it works perfectly because both case application runs in 32 bit mode.

So if i want to build application in Any CPU mode(without checking prefer 32 bit) and  run it properly , then what changes or installation i need to do? I want the application(same exe) to run in both 32 bit and 64 bit machine. Give me the best approach for this.

Note: If installing the 64 bit oracle in 64 bit machines is a solution then which reference i need to add to project ? 32 bit or 64 bit version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll ?